# Phonegap - Android - camera API not working

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I'm checking out PhoneGap API for android and was trying out the camera sample application example. 
I'm using phonegap 1.8.1 and my android version is 2.3.5.

I am trying to call the `navigator.camera.getPicture()` function from my
application but nothing happens.
I have included the correct `.js` file and other dependencies.
What can I be missing?

```
function capturePhotoURI() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhotoURISuccess, fail, 
            { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, quality: 50 });
    }
```

Comment: I have similar problem, but I fixed the issue. I have posted my answer on this thread. Please check the link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690388/phonegap-cordova-3-0-0-navigator-camera-is-undefined/26875054#26875054

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the destination type to

```
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a well known problem. You can see additional information about it on this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/GFwv2OticKw).

In short, we could describe the problem this way:

*When the Camera launches, the PhoneGap (Cordova) Activity is sometimes destroyed by the garbage collector from Android OS in order to free up memory.*

The best solution I have found so far is to use the "[ForegroundCamera](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ForegroundCamera)" plugin from the "[phonegap-plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)" repository.